# How to remove leading numbers and whitespace from a document with python

Tags: text-processing, python

I have long file with the following format.

```
123.I am biniyam sdfjhjkhkjsfsd \n
    sdfhhkjhkjhksdfl \n
14.I am in cybersecurity \n
   fdkjskdlfnmnjhuksnfe,h \n
872.I love soccer. \n
```

I wanted to remove the numbers and have them in the following format.

```
I am biniyam sdfjhjkhkjsfsd
sdfhhkjhkjhksdfl
I am in cybersecurity
fdkjskdlfnmnjhuksnfe,h
I love soccer.
```

Comment: Hi biniyam getu, you'll need to give some information about what you're stuck on rather than asking us to write the program for you.  Also python programming questions are best directed to Stackoverflow.com.  You might want to look into the [python-docx library](https://pypi.org/project/python-docx/)

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to write a python script? This is a small job for a stream editor:

```
sed 's/^[0-9]\{1,\}\.//;s/ \\n$//' yourfile
```

This would even make the question on-topic here at U&L.